# blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, angular7

Me esta saliendo el siguiente error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:59035/api/PaymentDetail'
> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

estoy tratando se solucionar este error de la siguiente manera

```
import { PaymentDetail } from './payment-detail.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PaymentDetailService {
  formData: PaymentDetail= {
    CVV: null,
    CardNumber: null,
    CardOwnerName: null,
    ExpirationDate: null,
    PMId: null
  };

  readonly rootURL = 'http://localhost:59035/api';
  list : PaymentDetail[];


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    postPaymentDetail() {
      const headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

         let OPTIONS = new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
return this.http.post(this.rootURL + '/PaymentDetail', this.formData,{headers:headers});
    }
```

Pero en estas líneas me esta saliendo lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que es lo que debo hacer para solucionar este problema de  blocked by CORS, de esta manera si se soluciona?

Angular 7

Cliente

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using WebAPI.Models;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddDbContext<PaymentDetailContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
            services.AddCors(options => {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                Builder=>Builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().WithMethods("GET","POST","DELETE","PUT")
                );
            });

        }


        //        .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        //    var resolver = options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver;
        //    if (resolver != null)
        //        (resolver as DefaultContractResolver).NamingStrategy = null;
        //});


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }


            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
            app.UseCors(options =>
            options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `headers` es una variable local no debes usar `this` para llamarla. Y la política de CORS debe cambiarse en el servidor no en el cliente.

Comment: Si lo siento publique una cosa que estaba ensayando, pero resulta que desde el servidor ya puse el cors

Comment: Mira ahí subí el startup

Comment: Bueno hay varias formas de hacerlo. Puedes probar con esta guía de microsoft https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#enable-cors